# I am loading the i18n but still gives me error when I run the server

Tags: python, django, internationalization

So I am using i18n tag and it works very well in all pages... I made a new app and added a template to it and I used {% trans '' %} to translate the strings but it gives me error when I submit a form in the page[image]

Can anyone tell me what can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The error here tells you the problem, you need this in every template that uses it:

```
{% load i18n %}
```

You say you're already loading the tag, but it's the only possible cause. This is also the case in an `{% include %}`ed template, even if the including template is already loading the tag. If it's not working, you might need to restart the server, as changes to templates are not always picked up during runtime.

Note also that the `{% trans %}` tag has been renamed to `{% translate %}`, but the old syntax still works.

Comment: I am already using {% load i18n %} and this is my problem that although I'm using it, it's not working

Comment: And you restarted the dev server?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by this "this is also the case in an {% include %}ed template, even if the including template is already loading the tag."

Comment: Yes I restarted the server

Comment: For example, if you have one template that includes another, the one that uses the tag needs to load it. It needs to be loaded in every file where it's used.